# Write on GCP bucket from TPU vm

Tags: google-compute-engine, huggingface-transformers, google-cloud-tpu

I am training a bert model using a TPU vm on GCP.
I want to use my bucket as the Datasets library Cache filepath. I have followed instructions from
https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert-2.x and set my bucket link in the `HF_DATASETS_CACHE` environment variable.

But I am getting this error : `Exception in device=TPU:0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs:/darijabert_bucket/datasets_Cache`

my `HF_DATASETS_CACHE` is set to gs://darijabert_bucket/datasets_Cache

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest that the specified bucket does not exist. Does the bucket `gs:/darijabert_bucket/datasets_Cache` exist in your project and in the correct region? You can double check to see if it exists by checking it in the GCP console.

Also, make sure that the bucket exists in the same region as your TPU VM, as the tutorial states:

```
The bucket location must be in the same region as your Compute Engine (VM) and your Cloud TPU node.
```

Comment: Thanks. My bucket exists on my project and iti is Multi-region whereas the tpu vm is on europe-west4-a. You think Multi-region is not ok and it must be in europe-west4-a?

Comment: Hmm, I think multi-region should be fine. With that said, I'd recommend you to still try to create a bucket in `europe-west4-a` and try again.